# How to reset session context/variables in JDBC pooled connections - MySQL / Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, jdbc, connection-pooling

In my application I have multithreads that needs to access database and I am using [apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/index.html?org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSource.html) as a JDBC connection pool.

In some cases users execute stored procedures that might affect the database session context/variables before executing another query to retrieve some data.

Is there a way to enforce closing the connection instead of just returning it to pool. Or how can we clear/reset the connection session context/variables for MySQL or Oracle using a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

[DBMS_SESSION.CLEAR_ALL_CONTEXT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SESSION.html#GUID-D89A115F-309E-41F8-A4C6-8505826389FA)

> This procedure clears application context information in the specified
> namespace.

[DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SESSION.html#GUID-CEC0FC4B-6520-4A79-A0C9-32C1ACAC552A)

> This procedure de-instantiates all packages in this session. It frees
> the package state.

Comment: Are both compatible for Oracle and MySQL? or what is the equivalent in MySQL.
For case similar to this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990609/changes-to-database-session-context-persists-with-pooled-connection-reuse?noredirect=1&lq=1] and this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65796032/changes-in-database-session-context-persists-with-pooled-connection-reuse] which procedure should we use? and whats the best way to call them from Java